# Why android studio designer is not working for relative layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout

[image: Android studio designer]

is not auto generating XML codes for relative layout, it only works for constraint layout.

When I try to position a view inside a relative layout it only gets positioned at the top corner of the screen.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button7"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button" />
</RelativeLayout
```

What should I do?

Comment: Do you know what a RelativeLayout is? If not, I suggest reading about it first  Maybe this can help https://abhiandroid.com/ui/relative-layout or the official page https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/relative

Comment: What actually you want? Want to show the button to center position?

Comment: Yes that is what i want. I was able to do it before with previous versions of android studio but after updating android studio it is not working.

Comment: How do you set up the position of the button? To set the position, you need to define the relationship between it with other views like the parent.

Comment: android studio 3.4 xml design view constraint not work. why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I faced the same issue and the i tried the following step;

- Click on the magnet icon (next to the eye icon, top left, next to the Palette menu) so that it's not crossed out: this turns on Autoconnect.
- this will now help you to move the button where ever you want to place it.

Try it and let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Yes if you pull the component on ConstraintLayout, it will guess what you want and set the attributes for you.
For RelativeLayout, you need to make the attribute view visible and edit from there. You need to edit parameters like these:

```
 android:layout_below="@id/name"
 android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
 android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/times"
```